# How to combine node.js and Java buildpack in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, heroku, gruntjs

We have an application that is a HTML5/JavaScript frontend that communicates with a pure Java backend via REST. The JavaScript frontend relies on Backbone.js rather than Node.js. For now, this is packaged as one application, and deployed in Heroku using the standard Java buildpack.

But what we want to do now is to add Grunt to the build process, in order to concatenate, minify, etc, the JavaScript. It works fine locally, but how would we make it work with Heroku?
We are not interested in committing the Grunted files. We want it to be a part of the buildpack. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom buildpack that supports both Java and Node. Take a look at [third-party buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks) and [multi buildpacks](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). Supporting Node will let you run Grunt.

Comment: Getting error:
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed...Please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596095/heroku-multi-buildpack-not-able-to-build-java-and-node