# multi buildpack - not able to build java and node

Tags: java, buildpack, cloud-foundry

Following this https://docs.cloud.gov/apps/multi-buildpack-deploys/ tutorial,

I'm trying to build java and node buildpacks and my build pack contains the below URLs

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

[image]

Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed, how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try using `cf logs nodeandjava --recent` for more information?  That will only give recent information, so you might want to push again, and then run that command to see logs relevant to your staging failure.

Comment: I need a cloud foundry app that run both java and nodejs app, It can be a simple hello world application, Anybody can help?

Comment: Why not use two separate apps? You can still manage them in one manifest if you need it.

Comment: @Udhaya any update on this. are u able to do so